# How do I run a executable file with command line arguments?

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

I wrote a C file and then compile it. I have to run it with different command line arguments and observe the result. I like to write a shell script in linux which runs my executable file with different arguments. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming your program needed the following arguments,  
# here is the bash script. Remove the echo to run it.
args=("-c 1 -d 2 -f a" "-c 2 -d 22 -f b" "-c 6 -d 12 -f z")
IFS='\n'
for arg in ${args[@]}
do
    echo yourexcutable $arg;
done
```

Comment: Modifying `IFS` prevents some of the issues with unquoted `${args[@]}` but not all of them. It isn't really a good way of doing this.